# Multiple select statements with joins, Multi-part identifier could not bound

Tags: sql

Error message:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 78
> The multi-part identifier "C1.Name" could not be bound
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 78
> The multi-part identifier "C2.Name" could not be bound

I think it's because of both C1.Name & C2.Name is not bounded with the Alias R?

```
SELECT  
    R.MapID AS MAPID, C1.Name AS IDFrom, C2.Name AS IDTo, R.Distance
FROM 
    (SELECT
         R.MapID AS MAPID, C1.Name AS IDFrom, C2.Name AS IDTo, R.Distance,

     FROM
         ROAD R
     INNER JOIN 
         CITY C1 ON C1.ID = R.IDfrom
     INNER JOIN 
         CITY C2 ON C2.ID = R.IDto) R
```

If I try to use Select * in the outer select it actually Works but adds the seqnum column, which I don't want

Comment: Outside of your subquery, `C1` and `C2` have no context; the subquery is aliased `R`, not `C1`, etc.

Comment: Yes, alias the correct object, `R`, in the outer query.

Comment: And don't re-use the same alias - just adds confusion.

Comment: It should be `R.IDFrom` and `R.IDTo`. You named them in the inside subquery.

Comment: @marcos right on the money. Thanks alot

Comment: It's both a table alias ***and*** a column alias problem.

Comment: I think the problem is because you aliased the subquery as `R`, which is the same as `ROAD`, and probably got you confused. Try to use different aliases to be more clear on you queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a derived query like the above (creating a temp table using another query), the aliases are local. The below tables can only be called within the brackets of your FROM:

```
ROAD R
INNER JOIN CITY C1 
ON C1.ID = R.IDfrom
INNER JOIN CITY C2
ON C2.ID = R.IDto
```

At the end you have alised that derived table to R, which means that any data you need from within the brackets needs to be aliased to R (See Below)

```
 SELECT  R.MAPID,  R.IDFrom, R.IDTo, R.Distance
 FROM (
       SELECT
          R.MapID as MAPID,  C1.Name as IDFrom, C2.Name as IDTo, R.Distance,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY R.MapID ORDER BY R.distance DESC) AS seqnum
       FROM ROAD R
       INNER JOIN CITY C1 
       ON C1.ID = R.IDfrom
       INNER JOIN CITY C2
       ON C2.ID = R.IDto 
 ) R
 WHERE R.seqnum = 1
```

It is also best practice to alias all Columns throughout the query so I have added `R.seqnum = 1`

Comment: @Cicada3301 yes thats correct. I completely forgot about that part. I'll edit that now

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  R.MapID as MAPID,  R.IDFrom, R.IDTo, R.Distance
 FROM 
    (SELECT
          R.MapID as MAPID,  C1.Name as IDFrom, C2.Name as IDTo, R.Distance,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY R.MapID ORDER BY R.distance DESC) AS seqnum
     FROM
          ROAD R
          INNER JOIN CITY C1 
          ON C1.ID = R.IDfrom
          INNER JOIN CITY C2
          ON C2.ID = R.IDto ) R
 WHERE  
      seqnum = 1
```

Comment: Yes, it is *both* a table alias and a column alias problem.  This answer looks like it addresses both problems.